# SQL Server 2016 upgrade from standard to developer edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

my DBA college have wrongly installed SQL Server 2016 Standard instead of SQL Server 2016 Developer edition. I took some time to google this situation and haven't found real-life experiences with the edition upgrade.

I know that Edition upgrade can be performed but I am wondering about the impact made on this instance. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the old one and install the new one.

Comment: You'll have to remove the Standard edition anyway: Standard => Money, Developer => Free. The DBA will want to reuse that license or revoke it, if it came from a volume license program like AA or Open